Как достать из текста все Digital Object Identifier
Мне нужно в тексте в любом месте обрабатывать ссылки, к примеру:
1. http://my.site.com/site/1
2. https://my.site.com/site/1
3. 11.111/1111-111A.11.1.11
4. 44.44444/aaaaa.4444444444

То есть мне в тексте придется доставать и doi и http.
И если это не сложно уследить, как-то захватить ссылки, внутри которых в случайном месте может оказаться пробел, который в свою очередь не нужен.
Пример текста:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
Rem optio debitis atque doloribus dolor nesciunt dictar! http://my.site.com/site/1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
Rem optio debitis atque doloribus dolor nesciunt dictar! http://my. site.com/site/1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
Rem optio debitis atque doloribus dolor nesciunt dictar! 11.111/1111-111A.11.1.11

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. 
Rem optio debitis atque doloribus dolor nesciunt dictar! 44.44444/aaaaa.4444444444


11.111/1111-111A.11.1.11 и 44.44444/aaaaa.4444444444 --- это не ссылки и не URL и никогда ими быть не могут

"захватить ссылки, внутри которых в случайном месте может оказаться пробел" --- это невозможно. Или как минимум должен быть список, который оглашает - что есть ссылка, а что есть следующее слово. Но тогда работа это уже не для регулярки

@АлексейШиманский Да это не ссылки а DOI.

@АлексейШиманский А если не для регулярки, что может помочь в моей ситуации?

@АлексейШиманский А если допустим игнорировать пробелы, то есть работая только с полными ссылками, для отслеживания DOI и HTTP мне нужно будет прописать 2 регулярки или 1?

даже если можно впихнуть всё в одну регулярку - выглядеть это будет нечитабельным месивом. Желательно для каждой задачи делать осмысленные для них действия. Поэтому лучше две регулярки, с индивидуальными правилами под каждую из сущностей
